# How to get the state(enabled/disabled) of safari content blocker app extension from safari toolbar item app extension?

Tags: safari-content-blocker, safari-app-extension

I am developing the mac app with Safari Content Blocker and Safari Toolbar Item extensions.

I am able to get the state of Content Blocker extension (enabled/disabled) in Safari from the mac app (Containing App), and able to display the warning inside the mac app that Content Blocker is disabled.

But is there any way that I can get the Content Blocker extension's state (enabled/disabled) from the Safari Toolbar Item extension?

Here is the code that executes when the popover is visible when a user clicks on Safari Toolbar Item.

```
class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {

    // This function is called from the 
    // SafariExtensionHandler > popoverWillShow(in window: SFSafariWindow)        
    func onPopoverVisible() {

        SFContentBlockerManager.getStateOfContentBlocker(withIdentifier: "com.xyz.macapp.contentblocker") { (state, error) in
            guard let state = state else {
                 // handle the error
                 return
            }
            if state.isEnabled {
                // display toolbar items and hide warning message
            } else {
                // display warning message and hide toolbar items
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When above code executes, `state.isEnabled` is always `false`.

Is it possible to get the state of one extension from another? If yes, how?. If no, is there any way to handle this scenario?